# Embedded QuickSight dashboard with URL Action to another dashboard

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Scenario:

I have a QuickSight dashboard embedded into the web application which is appearing correctly.

This dashboard (Dashboard A) contains a URL action which links to a seperate dashboard (Dashboard B).

I used Chrome Tools to grab the embed URL for dashboard B and configured it as the URL Action in the Analysis:

```
https://eu-west-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/embed/yyyyyyyyyyyYYYYYYYYYYYyyyy/dashboards/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

Now when the URL Action is clicked on the embedded Dashboard A, it correctly links to Dashboard B.

However if another user accesses the same embedded Dashboard A and clics the link, it results in

```
We can't display this page (Not authorized).
```

It seems like the first parameter `yyyyyyyyyyyYYYYYYYYYYYyyyy` is user specific, so the URL Action for Dashboard B cannot be hardcoded like this.

What is the correct approach for linking between embedded QuickSight dashboards. Is URL Actions the way to go, or is an alternative approach required?

### Solution

The "embed token" (`yyyyyyyyyyyYYYYYYYYYYYyyyy`) for the URL Action must be passed from the client side embed script as a parameter. The value to be passed can be retreived by parsing the session URL from Dashboard A.

```
    const embed = () => {
        const options = {
            url: props.sessionUrl,
            ...
            parameters: {
                embedToken: props.sessionUrl.split('/')[4]
            },
            ...
        };
        QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(options);
    };
```

Then in QuickSight the parameter can be used to form the URL for the URL Action as follows. (Make sure to add `embedToken` as a `string` as parameter in the Quicksight analysis).

```
https://eu-west-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/embed/<<$embedToken>>/dashboards/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

Embedded Dashboard A then correctly links to embedded Dashboard B when viewed by any user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative could be to generate the embed URL for dashboards A and B separately in your web application and pass the embed URL of Dashboard B as an external parameter for Dashboard A. Since you can use parameters inside an action URL, it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Bastien R. Solution added in original post.